# AWS CLI : Issue with "delete-item" request

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

i am having issues getting particular delete-item request to work through the AWS CLI.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Perform a scan operation on my DynamoDB table to return all results that match a filter expression on a field that ISN'T the partition key
2. For all items that match this query, delete them from the table

Here is the command I am trying to run..

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--filter-expression "EnvironmentGroup = :EnvironmentGroup" \   
--expression-attribute-values '{":EnvironmentGroup":{"S":"deleteThisGroup"}}' \   
--table-name "MyTable"
--query "Items[*]" \   
# use jq to get each item on its own line   
| jq --compact-output '.[]' \   
# replace newlines with null terminated so    
# we can tell xargs to ignore special characters    
| tr '\n' '\0' \   
| xargs -0 -t -I keyItem \
# use the whole item as the key to delete (dynamo keys *are* dynamo items)
aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name "MyTable" --key=keyItem
```

So in the above example, I want to perform a Scan on the `MyTable` table and return all items that have the `EnvironmentGroup` field set to `deleteThisGroup`. I then want each of these items to be deleted from the table.

This isn't working for me. If I take out the delete-item line, the command works and returns a list of all the items, but if I add the delete-item back in, I get `Error parsing parameter '--key': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input: keyItem`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete-item is to delete one item
If you want to delete multiple items, use [batch-write-item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html)